# Row exceeds page width instead of going to next page

Tags: longtable, landscape

[image]I am using longtable in lanscape. My rows have lots of text and it exceeds the page width istead of passing over to next page (pic 1). Apparently you cant divide a row between pages, this makes the pages go empty because usaually only 1 row fits the size. How do I make rows passover to next page.

Comment: Was there supposed to be a picture attached?

Comment: You should provide a MWE. Take a look this https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: If you need page breaks mid-paragraph you should be using a list not a table, but you have not given any information in your question that would allow anyone to make an answer